# Tengo problemas con NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Mi problema es, al crear yo, un proyecto, no me lo crea, sino, que, el programa lo que hace es que se queda en la ventana cuando el doy en finalizar (para crear el proyecto) entonces, nada, ahí queda, y si quiero editar un archivo con netbeans, no me deja dar enter para escribir abajo, sino, que en esa misma linea debo escribir todo el codigo. 
¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Adjunto la foto, como pueden ver, no me deja avanzar, sino, que se queda ahí y debo cerrar la ventana, tambien al momento de abrir un archivo .java trato de dar enter en el codigo para saltar a la siguiente linea y no me deja.

Comment: Hola Eduardo puedes subir una imagen del problema? para ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: He adjuntado la foto.

Comment: Estás usando un JDK o un JRE?

Comment: Estoy usando JDK